# Ansible YAML attribute reading

Tags: ansible, yaml

How can I select the cloud in my Ansible Playbook. Cloud nforce is now statically defined. As you can see in the last task of the playbook. But how can i implement the variable target_cloud to specify the cloud I want?

Ansible Playbook

```
---
- name: Get credentials from target Cloud
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    target_cloud: nfanthonydev
  tasks:

    - name: Load Clouds from file
      include_vars: clouds.yaml

    - name: Set credentials of target cloud in memory
      set_fact:
        os_auth:
          auth_url: "{{ clouds.nforce.auth.auth_url }}"
```

`clouds.yml`

```
clouds:
  nfbeheer:
    auth:
      auth_url: https://nforce-it.nl:5000/v3
      user_domain_name: Default
      username: kees
      password: kees_pass
      project_domain_name: Default
      project_name: nforce-beheer
    region_name: Steenwijk
  nfanthonydev:
    auth:
      auth_url: https://nforce-it.nl:5000/v3
      user_domain_name: Default
      username: anthony
      password: anthony_pass
      project_domain_name: Default
      project_name: nforce-anthonydev
    region_name: Groningen
  nforce:
    auth:
      auth_url: https://nforce-it.nl:5000/v3
      user_domain_name: Default
      username: piet
      password: piet_pass
      project_domain_name: Default
      project_name: nforce
    region_name: Groningen
```

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate with the marked one. What I need is to parse a variable to read the exact yaml attribute in the clouds.yml.

Comment: And the answer under the dup-target shows how you should do that.